# Table-valued function, table variable and "Must declare scalar variable" error message

Tags: sql-server

I am building a function that returns table result

```
ALTER FUNCTION [brm].[fnComputeScores_NEW]
(
    @var1 TINYINT
)
RETURNS 
@ret TABLE
(
    [producerid] INT
    ,[CityId] INT
    , CityName VARCHAR(100)
)
AS 
BEGIN


INSERT INTO @ret
        SELECT [producerid], [CityId] from producers

--placeholder

RETURN
END
```

everything is fine to this point

but code that I want to put in placeholder

```
UPDATE @ret
SET
    CityName = Cities.Name
FROM
    @ret JOIN Cities
        ON @ret.CityId= Cities.CityId
```

generates compilation error

> Must declare the scalar variable "@ret".

Why? How to fix it?

Comment: I know that in current sample I can have everything as a one statement.  But it works for current sample which is simplified version of real function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reference the table variable outside of `FROM`. This is not exclusive to `UPDATE`... from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175010.aspx:

> Outside a FROM clause, table variables must be referenced by using an alias...

...so you can try:

```
UPDATE r
SET
    r.CityName = c.Name
FROM
    @ret AS r 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Cities AS c
    ON r.CityId = c.CityId;
```

Comment: had the opposite experience.  Using the alias of the temp table wasn't working but using the name did.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as the OP.  I had table variables in a function and I was getting the error

```
"Invalid use of side-effecting or time-dependent operator in 'UPDATE' within a function"
```

Except, when I change the update statement to use the actual name of the table variable instead of the alias, it worked.  The function was a multistatement function and the table variable was the result table (defined at the beginning of the function).  Not sure why why it worked, but I would suggest trying that as a solution.

So for example, I changed:

```
update c
set column1=c.someValue+o.someValue
from @table as c inner join [otherTable] o on c.ID=o.ID
```

into:

```
update @table
set column1=c.someValue+o.someValue
from @table as c inner join [otherTable] o on c.ID=o.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't HAVE to use an alias; you can actually do the following:  (The problem seems to be in the SQL parser).  Notice the brackets around @ret.

```
UPDATE @ret
SET
    CityName = Cities.Name
FROM
    @ret JOIN Cities
        ON [@ret].CityId= Cities.CityId
```